# Mês e dia invertido ao salvar no banco de dados

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, jquery-ui, datepicker

Estou usando `datepicker` do `jqueryUI` para escolher a data em um calendário, o problema é, se escolho `04/12/2017` é salvo no banco `12/04/2017`.

datepicker:

```
$('#schedulingCalendar').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                beforeShowDay: function(date){
                    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-yy', date);
                    return [ $.inArray(string, arrayDaysToshow) >= 0 ]
                },
                onSelect: function(){
                    $('#schedulingCalendar').removeClass('input-validation-error');
                    $('#messageSchedulingDate').hide();
                    $('#messageCheckDate').hide();
                },
                onClose: function(){
                    $("#panelCalendar").animate({'height': '100%'}, 150);
                }
            });
```

Se eu mudar o `dateFormat` para `yy/mm/dd`, salva corretamente no banco, lembrando que esse problema **ocorre apenas em produção**, em **debug funciona normal**.

**OBS:** debugando o código ate o momento do `SaveChanges` (uso repository) a data esta correta (`04/12/2017`) porem ao consolidar no banco esta `12/04/2017`

**EDIT** 
outra coisa curiosa, estou usando o `ToString("d MMM yyyy")` para exibir a data após salvar, em debug exibe assim por exemplo `4 dez 2017` e no servidor exibe assim `4 Dec 2017`

Comment: Regional settings, já checou? em produção. abs.

Comment: Já tentou dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy' ? e na linha var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-MM-yyyy', date);

Comment: Qual o banco de dados você está usando?

Comment: Fiz um [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qd5wLg7p/) e seu código parece estar ok!

Comment: @Evandro mudar o `dateFormat` para o que você sugeriu coloca a data como `27/November/20172017` na viu.

Comment: @Fernando uso SQL Server

Comment: @Marconi sim está tudo funcionando bem, meu problema é essa inversão de dia e mês ao salvar no banco de dados, a exibição está okay

Comment: Está usando asp net mvc? O mvc recebe no formato mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: @MarcoAntonioQuintal sim uso MVC, a data é passada corretamente como `dd/mm/yy`

Comment: uma outra coisa que estou achando estranho é em desenvolvimento exibir a data em portugues assim `4 dez 2017` e no servidor exibir em inglês assim `4 Dec 2017`, quando uso `ToString("d MMM yyyy")`

Comment: Mas o asp net mvc vai pegar errado pois espera mm-dd-yyyy você terá que configurar para pegar corretamente. Tente colocar no model o attribute [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]